# Shaker Sort or Bi-directional Bubble Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently taking a Data Structure and Algorithm course, and part of an exercise is to implement the shaker sort algorithm with 3 for loops. In the code snippet contained a few error, which I fixed, but there is one thing I am not sure why I getting this:
When I initialize an array of the size 12, my first index value is not sorted, I don't understand why. **Here is my code:**

```
// Method which will sort an array by using the shakersort algorithm
public void shakerSort(int[] array)
{      

    for (int p = 1; p < array.length-1; p++)
    {

        for (int i = p-1; i < array.length-2; i++)
        {                
            if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            {
                super.swap(array, i, i+1);
            }            
        }

        for (int i = array.length-p-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            {
                super.swap(array, i, i+1);
            }
        }

    }
```

**My outcome was this:**

- Element 0: 53
- Element 1: 27
- Element 2: 28
- Element 3: 53
- Element 4: 90
- Element 5: 72
- Element 6: 80
- Element 7: 67
- Element 8: 2
- Element 9: 33
- Element 10: 45
- Element 11: 91
- After sorting...
- Element 0: 27
- Element 1: 2
- Element 2: 28
- Element 3: 33
- Element 4: 45
- Element 5: 53
- Element 6: 53
- Element 7: 67
- Element 8: 72
- Element 9: 80
- Element 10: 90
- Element 11: 91

Thanks for your time and help

-Daniel

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your code doesn't use `array[0]` at all.

In your last loop, you may want to swap `i` and `i-1`, not `i+1`.

Also, AFAIK, this is not shaker nor bubble sort: 
What you need to do is a main loop with 2 nested loops inside, one that goes from 0 to size-1 and the other from size-1 to 0, and between loops, test if you had to swap, if not, then your array is sorted.

[Take a look here for a clean implementation](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/bubblesort.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to make it work. And yes this is a Shaker/Cocktail sort. It's implementation uses nested for loops instead of do-while and a Boolean variable.